# Is it possible to copy this RFID fob, and if so what device would I need?

Tags: rfid

[image]

I've been reading up on this a bit but am having a hard time knowing exactly what I would need to be able to make copies of this specific key. I just know I am going to lose it and I don't want to have to pay excessive replacement fees each time I do, when it only opens an exterior gate. I know I am not savvy enough to build my own RFID reader and writer, but it appears I am not savvy enough even to know what one I would need to buy online.

Any help would be appreciated.
While my query is in my case specific to my product, information on the means of replicating RFID tags is liable to be of ongoing interest to others.

Comment: Without knowing what kind of rfid tag it is...

Comment: These parts cannot be copied in the same form-factor — only emulated, and the emulator is too big and power-hungry to carry it around with you all day (roughly 10 times the size incl. battery.)

Comment: @Passerby What beyond the pictures of the tag would be required to know what kind it is?

Thanks!

Comment: @Janka, what do you mean by emulated but not copied? Is it not possible to use some kind of read/write device to copy the data this fob sends and write it to a blank fob?

Comment: Those simple tags don't have an EEPROM because that one needs too much energy during programming. Instead, they are laser-coded in the factory. So there are no "blank fobs".

Comment: FCC ID for one would be a good place to start.

Comment: Who owns the gate?  Who makes the Gate? Who supplies replacements? What is  a reasonable replacement cost?

Comment: Serious comment: That carabiner is a loss-risk - the gates are easily knocked open - a screw lock gate is much more secure. AND the thin metal multiturn ring can easily lose keys off i t - in your photo one key has already started to escape down the spiral ring.

Answer (score 1):

- possibly it can copied, since it has no remote control switches visible,

http://fobcouver.ca/copying-process

http://fobcouver.ca/compatiblekeys

"We can only clone RFID scanning fobs. We can not clone the remote control portion." –

They have a variety of algorithms and donor tags ~$50, but you must contact them.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to copy the tag with this official programmer:
https://www.hidglobal.com/products/encoders/credential-encoders/programmer-1050

The datasheet of the tag is [HERE](https://www.hidglobal.com/sites/default/files/resource_files/prox-proxkey-iii-keyfob-ds-en.pdf).

I am copying my key tags at the place where you can also copy keys. They usually have multiple types of programmers.